# R STL and forecast package seems to get confused on this simulated data

Tags: r, seasonality

I have simulated data according to this DGP:

```
library(forecast)
n_sample = 256
time_onset = 25
time = seq(1, n_sample, length=n_sample)
ramp = abs(time-time_onset)/n_sample
a=0.15*((1+runif(n_sample)/1)**0.5)
b=sin(2*pi*time/n_sample*42)
d=0.65*(ramp+1)
y = a*b+d
forecast::findfrequency(y)
```

To my suprise the answer is 1.

If I put frequency of 1 in the STL package I cannot properly remove seasonality and I haven't found a method that properly removes seasonality using the STL package for this data.

the best I could do was with a frequency of 7 but strong seasonality is still left in the remainder

```
y_ts = ts(y,frequency=7)
y_stl = stl(y_ts, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)
plot(y_stl)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need R to find the frequency. You know the frequency because you generated the data. It is `n_sample/42 = 6.095`. However, STL requires integer seasonality, so it will not work exactly here.

```
y_ts <- ts(y, frequency = round(n_sample/42))
y_stl <- stl(y_ts, s.window = "periodic", robust = TRUE)
plot(y_stl)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for such prompt response and detailed answer.  This is correct, I am still wondering: (1) Seasonality still left because of the integer requirement, is there another function/library that may be able to deal with this , (2) in this case it's true that I don't need R to find the freq but why is R finding the wrong frequency of 1.

Comment: You could use a TBATS decomposition (via `forecast::tbats()`).